# Concatenating a double in a string truncates

Tags: java

For a variable `double spread = 0.135;` I'm writing

`"" + Math.round(spread * 10000) / 100 + "%"`

This is attempting to round to 1 basis point. (100 basis points = 1 %).

But it doesn't include any decimal part.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is yet another variant of *integer division truncates*; albeit slightly more deeply buried than normal.

`Math.round(spread * 10000)` returns an `long`. Dividing that by 100 will truncate the result to a `long`.

Your fix? Use `100.0` as the divisor. Then the expression is computed in floating point.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide a `long` by an `int` you get a `long` which is a whole number.  The simple solution is to divide by a double. Try

```
Math.round(spread * 10000) / 100.0 + "%"
```

or

```
Math.round(spread * 1e4) / 1e2 + "%"
```

Comment: I like the second one. I always forget that 1e2 is a floating point literal.

Comment: @Bathsheba it makes it clearer when all you really care about it the powers of 10 involved. I even use `1e1` for one decimal place sometimes ;)

Answer (score -1):

Round() returns a long. The div operation is thus a long value.

Comment: Not quite. Round on a `float` returns an `int`, on a `double` it returns a `long`.

Comment: It's worth clairfying that it's a `long` not an `Integer` or an `int`